# Service method arguments, object identifiers vs object references

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, architecture

I understand that it is probably better to pass objects into a service method, but is this still the case if the caller would first have to look up the object before calling the service?  And if so, why?

**Example**

Let's say I have a RoleService, that adds a role to the given user.  And let's say the RoleService is called via a web controller or possibly a REST API. The web controller takes the userId and roleId as input from the web request.

Would I be better off using this service method?

```
public void addRoleToUser(long userId, long roleId) {
    User user = userRepository.find(userId);
    Role role = userRepository.find(roleId);
    user.addRole(role);
}
```

Or this one? The web controller would obviously need to retrieve both objects before calling the service in this case.

```
public void addRoleToUser(User user, Role role) {
    user.addRole(role);
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether called via a web controller or a REST API, the incoming request would only be giving the 2 ID's, so you have to do the `find()` calls somewhere.

You certainly cannot trust the caller to have up-to-date information about the two objects, and it's a waste to transmit the full objects if you're only going to use the ID's anyway.

It is common to have the service API also be the database transaction boundary (service class or method annotated with `@Transactional`), so it is best to have the service method do the `find()` and `addRole()` calls, so they all execute in a single database transaction.